# How do transform the RDD of lists to a RDD of zipped list?

Tags: pyspark, bigdata

**RDD 
( 
 List(1, 2, 3) 
 List('A', 'B', 'C') 
 List('a', 'b', 'c')
)**

I want to transform this to

**RDD 
( 
List(1,'A','a') 
List(2,'B','b') 
List(3,'C','c') 
)**

I want do this operation in PySpark without using collect operation?

I tried the following:

1. ```
   lst = [[1, 2, 3], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
   l = sc.parallelize(lst)
   lst_new = l.reduce(lambda x,y: zip(x, y))
   for i in lst_new:
       print(i)
   ```

```
output: 
((1, 'A'), 'aa')
((2, 'B'), 'bb')
((3, 'C'), 'cc')
```

```
Required output: RDD(List(1, 'A', 'a'), List(2, 'B', 'b'), List(3, 'C', 'c'))
```

So that I can convert it into a dataframe.

```
+--+---+---+
|A1| A2| A3|
+--+---+---+
|1 |  A| aa|
|2 |  B| bb|
|3 |  C| cc|
+--+---+---+
```

Comment: output for the second example seems wrong. I am getting `(1, ('A', 'a'))
(2, ('B', 'b'))
(3, ('C', 'c'))` by running second example.

Answer (score 1):

`RDD` works on `(key, value)` pair. When you `zip first RDD` with the `second RDD` then `values from first RDD becomes keys for new RDD` and `values from the second RDD becomes values for new RDD`.

Now understand by Example number 1 -

**Creating RDDS**

```
#Python Lists
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = ['A', 'B', 'C']
c = ['a','b', 'c']

#3 Different RDDS from Python Lists
rdda = sc.parallelize(a)
rddb = sc.parallelize(b)
rddc = sc.parallelize(c)
```

**Zipping One by One and checking `key, value` pair -**

```
d = rdda.zip(rddb)
print (d.take(1))
[(1, 'A')] # 1 is key here and 'A' is Value

d = d.zip(rddc)
print (d.take(1))
[((1, 'A'), 'a')] # (1, 'A') is key here and 'a' is Value

print (d.collect()) #This wouldn't give us desired output
[((1, 'A'), 'a'), ((2, 'B'), 'b'), ((3, 'C'), 'c')]

#To get the desired output we need to map key and values in the same object/tuple using map

print (d.map(lambda x:x[0]+(x[1], )).take(1))
[(1, 'A', 'a')]

#lambda x:x[0]+(x[1], )  Here x[0] is having tuple of keys (1, 'A') and x[1] is just a string value 'a'. Now concat key tuple and value (convert to tuple (x[1], ))
```

**Finally convert to DF**

```
d.map(lambda x:x[0]+(x[1], )).toDF().show()
+---+---+---+
| _1| _2| _3|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  A|  a|
|  2|  B|  b|
|  3|  C|  c|
+---+---+---+
```

**Hope this will help you to resolve the second example to.**